# Why my code is disregarding my conditionals?

Tags: python

When i try to insert in DB, my code just disregard the variable changes in my conditionals.

```
def finalizarExames():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Dados                   =   np.asarray(request.form.items())
        Cursor                  =   db.cursor()
        Identidade              =   randint(0, 1000)
        Diagnostico = 1
        Val_Apagar = 0

        for i in Dados:


            PuxaDados   = "SELECT valoresMin, valoresMax FROM valores_ref WHERE nomeExame = %s"
            Cursor.execute(PuxaDados, (i[0])) # Posteriormente, mudar para i[0]
            for Valores in Cursor.fetchall():

                if float(i[1])  <   Valores[0]:
                    Diagnostico = 0

                elif float(i[1])    >   Valores[1]:
                    Diagnostico = 2

                else: Diagnostico = 1

            InsereDados = """
            INSERT INTO 
                exames_realizados 
                (nomeExame, valores, diagnostico, identidade) 
            VALUES 
                (%s, %s, %s, %s)

            """

            Cursor.execute(InsereDados, (i[0], i[1], Diagnostico, Identidade))
            db.commit()
```

I want to change the variable "Diagnostico" to 2 or 0, but it just insert with "Diagnostico = 1" (default), even if i put some higher/lower value.

Comment: You don't appear to have confirmed that your query returns anything at all.

Comment: Exactly.  It seems like you might be using the default value (1, set at the top of the function).  It could also be that depending on the results you get that it actually is executing but you're ending on a row that would case `Diagnostico` to be set to 1.

Comment: You're overwriting `Diagnostico` each time through the `for Valores` loop, so the value when you insert will be from the last row. You probably need to move the `INSERT` into the loop.

Comment: I tried all those suggestions, but it still not working...:(

Comment: One side comment: thank you for using parametrized queries in your SQL instead of using `str.format` to generate your queries. Nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `INSERT` query into the loop, so you use the value of `Diagnostico` from each row, not just the last row.

But you can combine the `SELECT` and `INSERT` into a single query that does it all in the DB.

```
for i in Dados:
    InsereDados = """
        INSERT INTO exames_realizados (nomeExame, valores, diagnostico, identidade)
        SELECT nomeExame, %s,
            CASE WHEN %s < valoresMin THEN 0
                 WHEN %s > valoresMax THEN 2
                 ELSE 1
            END, %s
        FROM valores_ref
        WHERE nomeExame = %s
    """
    Cursor.execute(InsereDados, (i[1], i[1], i[1], Identidade, i[0]))
    db.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, i really didn't think to do something like this. But i tried execute this code, and it isn't inserting nothing. Can you help me please??

Comment: If it's not inserting anything, that means there are no rows that match `WHERE nomeExame = i[0]`